# How to convert date string to UTC format

Tags: c#, utc

I have a folder of .csv files that are all named by date. They look like this:

20200625210308.csv --> (yyyyMMddHHmmss)

I'm trying to compare these files by date so I can delete all except for the most recent.

Assuming I've already handled all the splitting, etc.; How do I convert `20200625210308` to a UTC date so I can compare the files?

Comment: You can turn the string into a date with DateTime.ParseExact. Search the docs for more details on the syntax.

Comment: You don't need to convert them - the files have names formatted in a SARGable format.  Just order them, or get the "last" file in the folder.  Or will that not work for some reason?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm relatively new in programming. I've not heard of SARGable format and my google searches bring me to information pertaining to SQL. Regardless, what I think you're saying is the files will always be in order because of the way the date/time string is formatted. Correct?

Comment: @JustinFeistner Yes. Just sort the file names as strings (i.e. lexicographically) and they will be automatically in date order as well.

Comment: Yes, exactly (echoing Sweeper here).  It usually comes up in SQL because the column value needs to be converted or otherwise run through a function to be searched on.  (Don't worry too much about being new - I've just spent a lot of time around date/time stuff, so that jumps out at me more; I have gaps in other areas myself).  One last question, I guess - do you need to convert the timezone/offset, or are these dates already in the UTC zone/`0` offset?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse & Sweeper, thanks for the responses. Yes, this is UTC zone 0 so we're good there. This really simplified my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert them to `DateTime` values: Your date/time string `20200625210308.csv` has a base name that is **ISO 8601 Compact Form**: `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`. ISO 8601 date/time values are ***designed*** to collate and compare properly.

A simple string comparison suffices.

Given a `string[]` of those filenames, `filenames`, all you need to say is

```
var mostRecentFileName = filenames.Max();
```

No need to over-engineer the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple console app to give you the algorithm to UTC.  You'll have to figure out what you want from the UTC result to do your own file date comparison afterwards.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace DateTimeFormatTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string format = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(GiveMeTheDateTimeInUtc("20200625210308"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string GiveMeTheDateTimeInUtc(string filename)
        {
            var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(filename, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return dateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nit: `format` should probably be `readonly`.  More concerning, however, is the use of `ToUniversalTime()`, which treats the source datetime as if it were a local time - if the filenames are **not** in the timezone of the current process, the returned values will be off.